# Displaying map overlay in Final Cut Pro

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, tracking

I often see a map overlay in people's driving videos (showing a map in a corner that moves along the street to match the camera location of the main video as they drive through a street).

How do I create this? I use FCPX on a Mac.

I'm aware of the Relive app, but the video that app creates is in 3D, and moves much faster than the driving speed. I'm looking for a 2D version which show the video moving at the actual driving speed, and shows street names.

If not possible through an app, perhaps I can import the gpx data into a software that creates such an animated video.

I'm grappling for the best way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With a quick search I found this [website](http://www.tripgeo.com/Directionsmap.aspx), simulating a drive with google maps. When you have your maps simulation you should be able to easily match the speed with FCPX to the footage.